# Audio on TS File Falls Progressively Out of Sync

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I would really appreciate some help with this...

I have a .ts file I've downloaded from the internet, when I play in Quicktime the video progressively falls behind the audio. It becomes noticeable after a couple of minutes and is a few seconds out after about ten minutes. It plays fine in VLC, but I want to be able to play on my AppleTV which does the same as Quicktime.

I've tried everything I can think of to resolve...

- Convert with VLC, which does work, but every few seconds the audio skips.
- Convert with Handbrake, which again works, but every few seconds the audio skips like with VLC.
- Convert with FFMpeg using -async, but I get the same result again with the audio skips.
- Extracted the audio and video to two separate files and recreated a new file with FFMpeg, this makes no difference and is the same as playing the original file.
- Tried "stretching" the audio with FFMpeg using "aresample=async=1000", which synchronises but the audio is distorted.

I think the audio skips I'm getting from the -async option are caused because the audio is being trimmed to sync with the video. What I want to do is adjust the video to fit with the audio and leave the audio unchanged.

I've tried to do this with -vsync, but the the results are the same as the original file. The FFMpeg user guide says the following:

***With -map you can select from which stream the timestamps should be taken. You can leave either video or audio unchanged and sync the remaining stream(s) to the unchanged one.***

But I cannot figure out the syntax. This is what I'm trying but the output is the same as the original...

***ffmpeg -vsync 1 -I test.ts -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -y test.mp4***

I've tried the above using vsync with 0, 1 and 2, but the result is still the same.

Could anyone please help me with the syntax to sync the video stream to the audio stream and leave the audio unchanged? Or suggest an alternative method I could use?

Any help would be really, really appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the ffprobe for test.ts...

ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'TEst.ts':
Duration: 02:13:05.51, start: 1.406000, bitrate: 4579 kb/s
Program 1
Metadata:
service_name    : Service01
service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 1411200000.00 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s